# How to make texts appear below icons in Buttons (Material UI)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

Basically, this is my Button right now
[image]

I want to make the `Dummy Button` text to appear **below** the icon, how do I do that?
Here is my code

```
<Button className={classes.dummyButton}>
  <Image
   src="/buttonImage1.webp"
   alt="buttonimage1"
   width={48}
   height={48}
   />
<span>Dummy Button</span>
</Button>
```

Styles.js

```
dummyButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put your image tag in another span and change its display to `block`.

Try this:

```
<Button className={classes.dummyButton}>
 <span className={classes.mySpan}>
  <Image
   src="/buttonImage1.webp"
   alt="buttonimage1"
   width={48}
   height={48}
   />
</span>
<div>Dummy Button</div>
</Button>
```

and your class styles should be like this:

```
.mySpan {
       display: 'block'
    }
```

Comment: It is semantically "incorrect" to nest a div in a button. You should use the `<span>` element instead.

Comment: There still is `<div>Dummy Button</div>` nested in the button.

Comment: I know, maybe he needs his div in his button

Answer (score 2):

You want to set `display: 'flex'` and `flexDirection: 'column'` for column-direction elements placement inside your button:

```
dummyButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

try To add A `<br />` tag between image and div. This what I meant.
This will help you https://codepen.io/ash_000001/pen/OJOQaGp?editors=1100

```
<Button className={classes.dummyButton}>
  <Image
   src="/buttonImage1.webp"
   alt="buttonimage1"
   width={48}
   height={48}
   />

<div>Dummy Button</div>
</Button>
Styles.js

dummyButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
 
  },
```

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work

Comment: I added some padding. Try that or just replace padding with margin.

Comment: unfortunately, adding padding only makes the buttons bigger, margin also doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't use `<br>` to position elements.

Comment: This is an easy thing but I just don't have the real code that's why I can't practice to completion.

Answer (score 1):

It is semantically "incorrect" to use a `div` in a `button`. You should use the `span` element instead.

With that being said, the Button component uses flexbox to control the layout/alignment of content. To align the content vertically (so the icon is above the text), you can simply change the flex-direction to column.

style.js

```
dummyButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
```

```
<Button className={classes.dummyButton}>
  <Image
   src="/buttonImage1.webp"
   alt="buttonimage1"
   width={48}
   height={48}
   />
   <span>Dummy Button</span>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to recreate the youtube bottom bar, and here is what I came up with.

```js
<AppBar position="fixed" sx={{ top: 'auto', bottom: 0 }}>
  <Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <IconButton color="inherit" sx={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <AssignmentTurnedIn />
      <Typography variant="caption">Tasks</Typography>
    </IconButton>

    <IconButton color="inherit" sx={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <CalendarMonth />
      <Typography variant="caption">Events</Typography>
    </IconButton>

    <IconButton color="inherit" sx={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <FitnessCenter />
      <Typography variant="caption">Habits</Typography>
    </IconButton>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

[image]